# How i can check a user getting banned?

Tags: javascript, html

My html doesn't work.
I wanna checking user are banned or not then i used:

```html
<html>
<head style="background-color:#171745"> 
      <style>
      h1 {
      color:white;
      }
      h3 {
      color:white;
      }
      h5 {
      color:gray;
      }
      p {
        color:white;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
    function checkCookie() {
    let ban = getCookie("banned");
    if (ban != "1") {
    alert("You are banned.");
    } else {
    window.location.replace("https://tuan-os.github.io/home")
    alert("Welcome");
  }
}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The user are banned will get a message say him are banned. The not banned user is redirect to tuan-os.github.io/home. But when i test it then the front my eyes is a blank and it no redirect like i think. And i wont the cookie is not detected by the verification....

Comment: There is no place from the function is being called.

Comment: @AbinThaha your edit removed the HTML OP posted which is relevant to the question. Can you please fix your edit?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to how this solves your requirement of banning users at all? Why wouldn't banned users just clear their cookies...?

Comment: @sinanspd, no, I had a copy of the code, and I can assure you that the edit doesn't break anything. There wasn't any html code at the time I edited. Let me edit the question and post the code OP posted.

Comment: @AbinThaha My bad. I thought there was some stuff in the body. My apologies.

Comment: Why does head have a style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not calling the function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }
  function checkCookie() {
    let ban = getCookie("banned");
    if (ban != "1") {
      alert("You are banned.");
    } else {
      window.location.replace("https://tuan-os.github.io/home");
      alert("Welcome");
    }
  }
  checkCookie(); // You should always call the function after creating
</script>
```

Secondly, there is no `getCookie` function by default. You should create one using the script like below if you want to get a cookie stored in the browser:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

Comment: Oh it working. I created other version like
`
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }
  function bannedChecker() {
    let BanRefreshActi = getCookie("banned");
    if (BanRefreshActi == "1") {
      alert("You are banned.");
    } else {
      window.location.replace("https://tuan-os.github.io/home");
      alert("Welcome");
    }
  }
  bannedChecker(); // check cookies
</script>
`